# UIImagePickerController opening as .camera instead of .savedPhotosAlbum

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, gallery

I am using these two separate buttons in order to open either the camera OR the imageGallery.
[image]

```
@IBAction func tapGal(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        NSLog("No Cam Fam")
    }
}

@IBAction func tapCam(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        NSLog("No Cam Fam")
    }
}
```

The Camera button is working just as it should, meaning it opens the camera, but the gallery button is also opening the camera.  I have double-checked to make sure that the gallery button is actually linked to the `tapGal` function.  I have also tried replacing `.savedPhotosAlbum` with `.photoLibrary`, but the result was the same.

Comment: Please look at your code closely. Look at the two `imagePicker.sourceType = ...` lines.

Comment: your code is the same so it's result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your method with new one.

Your mistake is you have passed same line of code for both method :

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
```

**instad of**

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum
```

**Replace below method with your one :-**

```
@IBAction func tapGal(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum



        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        NSLog("No PhotoLibrary")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func tapGal(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType. photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary // use PhotoLibrary, not camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        NSLog("No Cam Fam")
    }
}

@IBAction func tapCam(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        NSLog("No Cam Fam")
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon. Please include an explanation of what was wrong and how your code solves the issue. That makes for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix as pointed out by @rmaddy.
I needed to change `imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera` to `imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum`